# Account Lookup Dialog New Button

Tags: administration, app-development, setup

We have overridden the 'New' button with a wizard to help users enter all the required fields as well as to help them set the right parent-child relationship. However, the 'New' button on the Account lookup dialog is not overridden.

Does anyone know how to do that short of replacing the lookup dialog with our own VF pages?

If that's not possible, is there a way to customize the list of fields in that new Account form? I know how to customize the list of fields returned when a search is done but the list of fields for the new form is the same regardless of what fields I select.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "New" button on the Lookup dialog is only displayed if you have enabled Quick Create from Setup/Customize/User Interface. This also affects getting the Quick Create form in the sidebar. I think on new orgs this is enabled by default, but it's generally not a good idea, in my opinion.

Comment: I'd turn off Quick Create as well to just get rid of the New button. Using Quick Create bypasses your validation rules too.

Comment: @Daniel I have noticed that too. We did add some validation rules to prevent the issue as some required field were missing and the rules were not doing their job.

Comment: In particular, I had a customer that was creating Contacts that had no Account through a lookup field on Opportunity. So there were thousands of Contact records that were Private and pretty much invisible even to the owner.

Answer (score 1):

Both parts of your request are not possible (or were not the last time I checked, but I haven't seen any changes to this area in a long time).

My employer has built their own custom lookup system (in one product at least) in part because of these issues.

I consider it a major oversight in the platform as is, but outside of removing create perms on the profile to the relevant object there's not much you can do.

Comment: I'd second this, you'd need to create your custom vf lookup. Here's a great post on this topic http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/visualforce-lookup.html?m=1